# HTML Frame get exact URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm having trouble locating the exact URL that is inside a frame when I put the "src" and sail into the frame as I locate the exact current url?

Comment: Please clarify & state if the urls are on the same domain

Comment: Are in different domains

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the current URL of your iframe?  You can try:

```
$('iframe').contentWindow.window.location.href
```

This is assuming that you have only 1 iframe on the page.

Comment: I have an aggravating factor that the domains are different, this solution gives me access denied.

Using the Access-Control-Origin might work?

Comment: Is the other domain yours?

Comment: This is a hack I had to do at work, but on the page in the iframe you can use javascript to set the document.domain to your domain to get access to it.  You have to edit the source code of the other page.